The use of "Could"
Dear Members of the Forum,
Could you tell me please why we use "could"  in the text bellow.
I read the Grammar book about the use of Modal verbs. As far as I understand, could is usually used to say that somebody had the ability to do something, or was allowed to do something, when it comes to the events in the past. But it seems not to be the case here...
It doesn't express possibility either in this text, the more so because could is only used for what is possible now and in the future...
I'm really puzzled.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Text:
When I was a child, once a month, we used to go out together for cultural activities. We could visit museums and art galleries, or we could go to the concert, theatre and the like. It’s true that making choices did not always come easily to us. Some of us were fond of music, while the others might have been quite indifferent to it. But we were learning to make courageous compromises and always managed to find something appropriate that would meet all our demands. Sometimes, after that, we could go to a nice small restaurant, where we could sit and share our impressions, while enjoying good food.

'Could' is certainly used for possibility or ability in the past. Who told you otherwise? When I lived in London from 1990 to 2002, on Saturdays I could go to any of a large number of museums and art galleries. When I was aged 15, I could swim 100 metres in 90 seconds; now it would take me more than 120.

Actually, I read in Murphy, English Grammar in Use, 2019 : "...could is only used for what is possible now and in the future", for the past use "could have+past participle" (p. 54, Unit 27). And also in Swan, Practical English Usage. 2016: "Might/could + infinitive is not normally used to talk about past possibility (except in indirect speech)... However, to say that it is possible that something happened or was true in the past, we can use may/might/could have + past participle" (n° 71.7). Perhaps, I misunderstand what they mean...

In 71, Swan is discussing chances, not abilities. Look at Swan 82.3

Thank you so much Jeffrey Carney! Now I understand. In fact, I thought that ability and possibility were different things. But I have seen the definition of it in Swan 82.3: "We also use can to say what we are able (or unable) to do because of the circumstances that we are in - what is possible in the situation" )). So there are different possibilities: for the one (possibility in the sense of ability) we use could in the past, for the other (uncertain past possibilities) we use could have.

While "would" indicates things from the past that were a regular practice or habit (eg "when I was young I would go the beach"), "could" indicates possibilities - things that were possible, available to you.
Your quotation doesn't appear to be an account of what the writer necessarily did themselves when they were young, but rather the things that young people in general could do. When he uses the pronoun "we" it seems to be the inclusive 'we' which refers to one's peers - those with a shared experience in the scope of whatever context has been laid down. Even if he did all of the named activities regularly, to make it broader he has used "could" because not all children may have done all the things mentioned, but they could have.

Thank you very much, Astralbee, for your answer! I hope you don't mind my asking, but there is a phrase in the text: "We were learning to make courageous compromises and always managed to find something appropriate that would meet all our demands." I wonder if it is correct to use "would" in this case. On the one hand, it concerns past events so it should be "would have been", but on the other hand it is not an unreal conditional...
